# ubuntu 16.04 doesnot detect second screen while screen is locked

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Dell E6430 and connecting to it another screen using VGA cable , I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and whenever the screen is locked i must open the screen of the laptop to write the user name and password even if i choose to use only the external screen and disable the laptop screen then after the log on my settings work " only the external screen works and the laptop screen disabled "

Answer (score 0):

That is because the screen of your laptop is set as the main screen and the external screen is set as the 2nd screen. You can edit this by changing the order Settings -> and then turn off the slide of your internal screen. Now when you lock your screen the login should be on your external screen